# How can I reduce the speed of motors with given battery voltage?

Tags: batteries, robotics

I'm new to building line followers. I'm using ARDUINO UNO and a motor shield for accomplishing this task and for the power supply, I'm using a 12V Li-Po battery along with 2 300 rpm motors.

The problem I encountered is that the voltage provided by the battery to the motors is too high due to which the motors have really high speeds and can't follow the lines properly.

Is there any way by which we can regulate the voltage that is provided to the the the motors, externally or through any function of the ARDUINO IDE, so that the speed of the motors gets reduced and they can properly follow the lines?

Comment: you'll want a motor speed controller, not just a reduction in voltage. How to build one will depend on the type of motors you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Reducing the battery voltage by going to a lower voltage would go a long way to alleviate that. Is there anything on your robot that actually needs 12V? Or even 9V? Your motor shield CAN run at 12V but it can also run as low as 5V.

As for your motor shield, look up PWM. Basically quickly pulse power to your motor and it will allow it to run slower.

Answer (score 1):

Look for tutorial information about using the Arduino Uno with motor shield to control the speed. You should be able to do what you want with code. However, what you want may not be the best solution. If you never operate the motor at full speed, you are wasting motor capability. If that is the case, you should change the gear ratio. There is no reason not to reduce the speed electronically, but if you find that the motor stalls sometimes, you may need a different gear ratio.